# How do I make the Prime MessageService work in the Interceptor of an Angular application that only uses Standalone Components?

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-standalone-components, angular-httpclient-interceptors

I'm trying to implement a global error notification but I'm not managing to inject anything into the Interceptor and the worst thing is that it doesn't give an error, it just doesn't work, if anyone can shed some light, I'd appreciate it, below project specifications
-Angular v16
-Full standalone
-PrimeNG

main.ts

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideAnimations(),
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptors([ErrorHandlerInterceptor])),
    importProvidersFrom(MessageService, ToastModule),
  ],
}).catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

error-handler.interceptor.ts

```
export const ErrorHandlerInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
  console.log('here comes');
  const messageService: MessageService = inject(MessageService);

  console.log('Not here');

  messageService.add({
    severity: 'success',
    summary: 'Success',
    detail: 'Message Content',
  });

  return next(req).pipe(
    catchError((error) => {
      if (error.status === 0) {
      }
      if (error.status === 500) {
      }
      console.log('cath');
      return throwError(() => new Error(error));
    })
  );
};
```

I tried to create a service with the MessageService inside and even then it didn't help and it doesn't return any error, the HTTP call simply goes to limbo.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working simply by adding the provider at the root:

main.ts

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
   providers: [
       MessageService,
       ...
   ],
}).catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

my-component.ts

```
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [
        ...
    ],
    providers: [],
    ...
})
export class MyComponent {

    constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {}

    notify(): void {
        this.messageService.add({
                severity: 'warn',
                summary: 'message summary',
                detail: 'message details',
            });
    }


}
```